# Google Drive - Simultaneous Downloads

Tags: download, google-api, google-drive-api, quota, simultaneous

I have direct download links (urls) of about 200 files in my google drive.
How many people can download any of these files at the same time.

Is there a limit on simultaneous access by other users to my Google Drive file urls for read only access.

Thanks,
Gagan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no limit to the number of people who can access a file at the same time.  Read access has no effect on this.

There is a Quota Limit to how fast the application doing the download can run and how much it can access at the same time.

To view your allowed quota please create a project in the [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console). In the "Service" tab, the default quota allowed for each service is indicated.

Currently for the Drive API it reads "Courtesy limit: 1,000,000,000 queries/day". It's a per app quota.

After you've enabled the Drive API you can also set a per user rate limit (by default 1000 req per 100 sec) to prevent one user from depleting your app's quota. That's available in the "Quotas" tab.

Comment: Thanks for the info.